# Update objects with DRF Serializer with data from JSON

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I get a JSON response with data from multiple objects, run everything through the serializer and call  `serializer.save()` which creates new objects but doesnt update the existing ones.

view

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
serializer = CellCESaveSerializer(data=data, many = True, context = {'descriptoridlist' : descriptoridlist}, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

the serializer

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
        # convert list to string
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.rstrip(",")  # Needed because of JSON response
        data = data.split(",")  # Split string to list
        data = [int(i) for i in data] # convert str to int
        did = self.context['descriptoridlist']
        x = (did,data)   # Create Array
        return super().to_internal_value(x)

class CellCESaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    row = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name",queryset=Descriptor.objects.all() ) # foreignkey mit namen
    val = StringArrayField()   

    class Meta:
        model = CellCE
        fields = ('row','val')
```

How can i update the existing objects without creating new objects?

**EDIT 1:**

After adding @neverwalkaloner changes i realised i need to use ListSerializer to update multiple objects. I adjusted my code with help of the [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer). (I changed the serializer to a ListSerializer, added the id Field and the update method.)

serializer:

```
class CellCESaveSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    row = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name",queryset=Descriptor.objects.all()) # foreignkey mit namen
    val = StringArrayField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        model = CellCE
        fields = ('row','val')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        CellCE_mapping = {CellCE.id: CellCE for CellCE in instance}
        data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

        # Perform creations and updates.
        ret = []
        for CellCE_id, data in data_mapping.items():
            CellCE = CellCE_mapping.get(CellCE_id, None)
            if CellCE is None:
                ret.append(self.child.create(data))
            else:
                ret.append(self.child.update(CellCE, data))

        # Perform deletions.
        for CellCE_id, CellCE in CellCE_mapping.items():
            if CellCE_id not in data_mapping:
                CellCE.delete()

        return ret
```

I get the error:

```
AssertionError: `child` is a required argument.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Serializer's `save()` method check if serializer's `self.instance` is empty or not. If `self.instance` is empty `save()` will call `create()` method, otherwise it will call `update()` method.

So to update instance with serializer, you need to pass as it's first argument updating object:

```
obj = CellCE.objects.get(id='some_id') # Object wich will be updated
serializer = CellCESaveSerializer(obj, data=data, many = True, context = {'descriptoridlist' : descriptoridlist}, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to use ListSerializer because when you pass "many=True", it also use ListSerializer class. If you want to update once object, please include "id" field and pass its value in input data.

Comment: If i use the `serializer.ModelSerializer` class i get `NotImplementedError: Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update b
y default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with inse
rtions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a ListSeriali
zer class and override .update() so you can specify the behavior exactly.`

Comment: Yes, so if you use this serializer for update multiple, just override only update function of the serializer. Or if you use ListSerialier, it needs to pass the "child" property. It is a serializer class, will be used for update each item.